# Ошибка при запуске кода телеграм бота на Питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я конечно недавно начал, но эта ошибка сне не понятна, запускаю бота стандартно там всего одна команда `sendmassege` и всё, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Python 3.7.0 , среда разработки PyCharm.

Comment: Приведите ваш код в текстовом формате.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии питона 3.7 `async` и `await` являются ключевыми словами и они не могут использоваться в качестве названия классов, переменных, функций. Поэтому вам следует либо откатиться на версию питона 3.6, либо дождаться обновления pyTelegramBotAPI.

Comment: А что посоветуете вы, откатится до 3.6 или ждать объявления ?

Comment: Я бы откатился до 3.6. Но можно попробовать установить pyTelegramBotApi из github. Судя по соответствующему [issue](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/524) были внесены исправления.

Comment: Может я конечно туповат в плане питона:) Подскажите как откатить до 3.6, ёе нужно скачать так же как и 3.7 или через командную строку ?

Comment: Удаляете 3.7. Скачиваете 3.6 и устанавливаете.

Comment: Спасибо большое я уже так и сделал !)